# How to submit code to a remote Spark cluster from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark

I have two clusters, one in local virtual machine another in remote cloud. Both clusters in Standalone mode.

My Environment:

```
Scala: 2.10.4
Spark: 1.5.1
JDK:   1.8.40
OS:    CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
```

The local cluster:

> Spark Master: spark://local1:7077

The remote cluster:

> Spark Master: spark://remote1:7077

I want to finish this:

Write codes(just simple word-count) in IntelliJ IDEA locally(on my laptp), and set the Spark Master URL to `spark://local1:7077` and `spark://remote1:7077`, then run my codes in IntelliJ IDEA. That is, I don't want to use `spark-submit` to submit a job.

But I got some problem:

When I use the local cluster, everything goes well. Run codes in IntelliJ IDEA or use spark-submit can submit job to cluster and can finish the job.

But When I use the remote cluster, I got a warning log:

> TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

It is **sufficient resources** not **sufficient memory**!

And this log keep printing, no further actions. Both `spark-submit` and run codes in IntelliJ IDEA result the same.

I want to know:

- Is it possible to submit codes from IntelliJ IDEA to remote cluster?
- If it's OK, does it need configuration?
- What are the possible reasons that can cause my problem?
- How can I handle this problem?

Thanks a lot!

**Update**

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591481/running-spark-code-on-eclipse-with-spark-being-install-on-another-server), but I think my scene is different. When I run my codes in IntelliJ IDEA, and set `Spark Master` to local virtual machine cluster, it works. But I got `Initial job has not accepted any resources;...` warning instead.

I want to know whether the security policy or fireworks can cause this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running spark code on eclipse with spark being install on another server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591481/running-spark-code-on-eclipse-with-spark-being-install-on-another-server)

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto  But that other post (which is yours) does *not* show how to run directly from IJ: it requires building the jar and using `spark-submit`.

Answer (score 4):

Submitting code programatically (e.g. via `SparkSubmit`) is quite tricky.  At the least there is a variety of environment settings and considerations  -handled by the `spark-submit` script - that are quite difficult to replicate within a scala program. I am still uncertain of how to achieve it: and there have been a number of long running threads within the spark developer community on the topic.

My answer here is about a portion of your post: specifically the

> TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check
>   your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have
>   sufficient resources

The reason is typically there were a mismatch on the requested memory and/or number of cores from your job versus what were available on the cluster.  Possibly when submitting from IJ the

> $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf

were not properly matching the parameters required for your task on the existing cluster.  You may need to update:

```
spark.driver.memory   4g
spark.executor.memory   8g
spark.executor.cores  8
```

You can check the spark ui on port 8080 to verify that the parameters you requested are actually available on the cluster.