# Submit a Spark application that connects to a Cassandra database from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: windows, ubuntu, apache-spark, intellij-idea, cassandra

I found a similar question here: [How to submit code to a remote Spark cluster from IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607220/how-to-submit-code-to-a-remote-spark-cluster-from-intellij-idea)

I want to submit a Spark application to a cluster on which Spark and Cassandra are installed.

**My Application** is on a Windows OS. The application is written in IntelliJ using:

- Maven
- Scala
- Spark

Below is a code snippet:

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder().master("spark://...:7077") // the actual code contains the IP of the master node from the cluster
  .appName("Cassandra App")
  .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", cassandraHost) // is the same as the IP of the master node from the cluster
  .getOrCreate()

val sc = spark.sparkContext

val trainingdata = sc.cassandraTable("sparkdb", "trainingdata").map(a => a.get[String]("attributes"))
```

**The Cluster** contains two nodes on which Ubuntu is installed. Also, Cassandra and Spark are installed on each node.

When I use `local[*]` instead of `spark://...:7077` everything works fine. However, when I use the version described in this post, I get the next error:

```
WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

On the cluster, the error is detailed further:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyApplication$$anonfun$1
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
```

Also, I want to note that the application written on Windows uses Spark as a Maven dependency.

I would like to know if it is possible to submit this spark application from the Windows node to the Ubuntu cluster and if it is not possible, what alternative should I use. If I have to create a `jar` from the Scala object, what approach should I use call the cluster from IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to launch your application it should persist on cluster in other words your packaged jar should reside or in HDFS or in every node of your cluster at same path. Then you can use ssh client or [RESTfull interface](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) or whatever enables triggering spark-submit command.